# Updating web2py auth_user custom fields programmatically

Tags: python, data-access-layer, web2py

I have a custom field associated with user which stores the score of each user in the auth_user table using auth.settings.extra_fields with both readable=False and writable=False. But I want to update this field programmatically.

I tried the following:

auth.user.score.update(float(balance)-float(cost))

Both balance and cost are well defined variables and I checked returning them individually, which works. I had to try this because I found that it is not possible to access the auth_user table using DAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to access the auth_user table using the DAL. Have you tried:

```
db(db.auth_user.id == auth.user_id).update(score=float(balance) - float(cost))
```

Note, `auth.user` refers to a copy of the user record stored in the session, so changing it does not affect the database record.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was not possible to access it so since 
    (row = db(db.auth_user.id==auth.user_id)
    return str(row))
returned nothing for me.

Comment: Same is the case with the solution posted by you. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `db(db.auth_user.id==auth.user_id)` does not return a Row or Rows object -- it is just a DAL Set object (i.e., it defines the query but doesn't select the records from the db). To select the records, you need to do `db(db.auth_user.id==auth.user_id).select()`.

Comment: As far as where you're going wrong, it's hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Antony. Fixed the issue. The problem was that I was missing on db.commit() after the update and regards selection, it was the mistake that you were pointing out.

Comment: I assume you're doing the update at the command line or via a script. For regular HTTP requests, there is no need to call `db.commit()`, as that is done automatically at the end of the request handling.

Comment: This is a controller which I am invoking using an ajax call using the inbuilt ajax() helper. Guessing this works differently from a usual http request.

Comment: No, an Ajax request is the same as any other. You shouldn't need to call `db.commit()` in that case.